# Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I tried a bulk add as shown is your readme but instead I get this error:

```
"Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters"
```

The model I'm trying to add is just a test model, and it's something like:

```
"_id" => "57028f25633db3473d0041c8"
```

The data is coming from a Mongo DB instance

I am using Windown 10, Phpstorm, xampp, Laravel 5.5, jenssegers/mongodb, elasticquent/elasticquent 1.0, Elasticsearch 6.0.0,

My code :

```
\App\Product::createIndex($shards = null, $replicas = null);
\App\Product::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);
\App\Product::addAllToIndex();
```

Comment: _id is a internal and reserved field in elasticsearch. Try changing the layout if your documents or omit the _id field if possible.

Comment: I can't remove _id in the data because it's needed.  "changing the layout if your documents" I do not understand... Pls help me

Comment: in your elasticsearch model introduce a new field like internal_id and populate it with mongos _id.

Comment: Please have a look on the elasticseaech official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/5.0/index.html

Comment: I use elasticquent (https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent) to configure. I don't know how to fix it. 
Can you help me use "Elasticquent"

Comment: Tks you very much . I think I have solved my problem .... I do it by way.
  add    " protected $hidden = ['_id']; "  in Model

Comment: Hey, I am using logstash for passing data to the elastic search. I have solved this issue by putting in filter->mutate in logstash config file and assigning _id to some other field. rename => ["mongo_id", "_id"].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was redirecting the cloudwatch logs to ElasticSearch by terraform. This was resolved by adding `filter_pattern` for cloudwatch subscription filter (before it was empty).

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "cloudwatch_logs_to_es" {
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.cloudwatch_allow]
  name            = var.clw_subscription_filter_name
  log_group_name  = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.auth0_log_group.name
  filter_pattern  = "[host, ident, authuser, date, request, status, bytes]"
  destination_arn = aws_lambda_function.cwl_stream_lambda.arn
}
```